# Selenium WebDriver - drop down list contains only the first element when using HTLMUnitDriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to select an element in Selenium 2 from a drop-down list using this code:

```
WebElement przyczynaZakProcesuSelect = driver.findElement(
           By.name("j_id_t:j_id_41:0:j_id_4h:0:j_id_51:0:qstloop:0:select1" ));

        Select sel = new Select( przyczynaZakProcesuSelect );
        List<WebElement> lista = sel.getOptions();
        System.out.println( "List --> count of elements :" + lista.size());
        for( WebElement e: lista){
            System.out.println( e.getText() );
        }

        sel.selectByVisibleText("yyyyyy");
```

Everything works fine while using InternetExplorerDriver, this code prints all 15 options to the console, and I am able to select last `yyyyyy` option. This is an output printed to the console for 
InternetExplorerDriver

```
List --> count of elements :15
aaaaaa 
…….
……
yyyyyy
```

However, when using HTMLUnitDriver, Selenium retrieves only the first option in the list, all remainig options are lost, and I am able to select only the first option, this is what is printed to the console when using HTMLUnitDriver:

```
List --> count of elements :1
aaaaaa
```

This is a snippet of HTML code:

```
<select id="j_id_t:j_id_41:0:j_id_4h:0:j_id_51:0:qstloop:0:select1" 
        onchange="jsf.ajax.request('j_id_t:j_id_41:0:j_id_4h:0:j_id_51:0:qstloop:0:select1',event,
                  {execute:'@form',render:'j_id_t:processContent j_id_t:ccpmScripts ccpmMessages ',
                   'javax.faces.behavior.event':'change'})" 
        class="selectboxNew frmLOK" onfocus="a4j_focus(this)" 
        title="aaaaa" 
        size="1" name="j_id_t:j_id_41:0:j_id_4h:0:j_id_51:0:qstloop:0:select1"> 
<option title="aaaaa" selected="selected" value="4650">aaaaaaaaa</option>
<option title="bbbbb" value="4643">bbbbb</option>
<option title="ccccc" value="4651">ccccc</option>
....
....
<option title="xxxxx" value="4647">xxxxx</option>
<option title="yyyyy" value="4649">yyyyy</option>
</select>
```

What I am doing wrong ? Is there any workaround ? 
I need to run this test using HTMLUnitDriver, please help.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you did

```
driver.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
```

If you did, you can try emulating **specific browsers** like:

```
HtmlUnitDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_3);
```

You can also try co **click** on that select prior selecting values.

Make sure you understand the **driver's behavior** well - take a look at the [documentation](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/HtmlUnitDriver)

Unfortunately my experience is that the emulated driver won't work properly for bigger applications (I mean JavaScript). Especially when there are some browser-specific workarounds.

Comment: Thank you for suggestions, I will try to click on the select before selecting the value. In my code I am using `setJavascriptEnabled(true)` and `BrowserVersion.INTERNET_EXPLORER_8`

Comment: Yeah, it may just skip hidden or display:none elements.